# Filtering and sum issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that I put in sample.xlsx and the code that should filter the items "CIRS" and FX_FORWARDS from the INSTRUMENT column and sum the values from the NOMINAL_MAX column. However, in the indicated .Range it shows me the value 0.

```
Dim colHead As String
With wbMe.Sheets("pochodne")
If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    Nominal_MAX = "Nominal_MAX"
    colHead = "INSTRUMENT"
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rTable = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
    Set rCol = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=Nominal_MAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rCol1 = rTable.Rows(1).Find(What:=colHead, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
        .Range("T39").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), rTable.Columns(rCol.Column), "<>0", rTable.Columns(rCol1.Column), "CIRS", rTable.Columns(rCol1.Column), "FX_FORWARD"), 0)
    Else
        SumCriteria = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Your formula requires one column to have two different values at the same time, so will always return 0. Use two SUMIFS functions, one for `CIRS` and one for `FX_FORWARDS`, and then add them together.

Comment: And if I have the condition> 0 also do two functions?

Comment: Yes you need that condition in both.